# Error: “Programmatic Access To Visual Basic Project Is Not Trusted” when Adding commandbar on VBE by VSTO. (“Trust Access to the VBA Proj...” checked)

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to create a Word VSTO Add-In that adds a commandbar on VBE permanently.

My environment:

windows 10 (language: Traditional Chinese), office 365

Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) – 17.5.2, .Net Framework 4.8

I have modified the macro settings in Word host applications as follows:

File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Setttings -> Macro Settings ->checked “**Trust Access to the VBA Project object model**”.

I have added the following references:

“**Microsoft.Vbe.Interop**”

**VB.NET** Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim cb As CommandBar
        cb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.VBE.CommandBars.Add("testbar")
        cb.Visible = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

I have researched this issue and found that most solutions suggest checking 'Trust Access to the VBA Project object model' to allow the code to work.

However, despite enabling this checkbox, I still encounter the error message '**Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is Not Trusted**'.

[image]

(By using VBA code, I am able to add a command bar on VBE, but it does not maintain permanently.)

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

---

**update:**

I have done some testing and found the following results:

Even if I haven't added the Group Policy registry keys that *Eugene Astafiev* mentioned (highlighted in red box in the image below), as long as "Trust Access to the VBA Project object model" is checked in Trust Center, the Add-in can be built and run successfully, despite the error message "Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is Not Trusted" during the build process.

[image]

Checking **Trust access to the VBA project object model** and modifying Group Policy settings and Registry Key in Word, Excel, and PowerPoint doesn't solve the error message problem.

Comment: Why do you need to add a command bar for the VBA editor from your VSTO add-in?

Comment: Thank you for response. I am mainly looking to customize VBE UI.
I am not just want to add one command bar, but I simplified the issue for clarity.

My main goal is to implement the functionality of code snippets, where clicking a button will insert specific code. I also want to toggle the immediate window to be docked at the bottom or on the right by a button.

The add-in is currently functional, but there are still some issues, which I have updated in the latter part of my post. @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: Why do you need to use a VSTO add-in for such tasks?

Comment: In fact, I have already implemented the functionality of Code snippets using VBA (clicking a button to insert my predefined code). However, after clicking the button and inserting the code once, the program seems to be reset, and clicking the button again has no effect. If the button click event function only contains a Beep function and no instructions to insert the code(such as  VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.InsertLines 2, "hello world"), then clicking the button is always effective.

Answer (score 1):

> However, despite enabling this checkbox, I still encounter the error message 'Programmatic Access to Visual Basic Project is Not Trusted'.

You need to check other `Trust center` settings as well as group policy settings. For example, a corresponding group policy setting controls whether automation clients such as Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Microsoft Office (VSTO) can access the Visual Basic for Applications project system in the specified applications. VSTO projects require access to the Visual Basic for Applications project system in Excel, PowerPoint, and Word, even though the projects do not use Visual Basic for Applications. Design-time support of controls in both Visual Basic and C# projects depends on the Visual Basic for Applications project system in Word and Excel.

If you enable this policy setting, VSTO and other automation clients can access the Visual Basic for Applications project system in the specified applications. Users will not be able to change this behavior through the `Trust access to the VBA project object model` user interface option under the Macro Settings section of the Trust Center.

If you disable this policy setting, VSTO does not have programmatic access to VBA projects. In addition, the `Trust access to the VBA project object model` check box is cleared and users cannot change it. Disabling this policy setting prevents VSTO projects from interacting properly with the VBA project system in the selected application.

If you do not configure this policy setting, automation clients do not have programmatic access to VBA projects. Users can enable this by selecting the `Trust access to the VBA project object model` in the `Macro Settings` section of the `Trust Center`. However, doing so allows macros in any documents the user opens to access the core Visual Basic objects, methods, and properties, which represents a potential security hazard.

| Registry Hive | HKEY_CURRENT_USER |
| --- | --- |
| Registry Path | software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\word\security |
| Value Name | accessvbom |
| Value Type | REG_DWORD |
| Enabled Value | 1 |
| Disabled Value | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

The command bar is added every time the addin is initialized. To do this you have to permanently add your addin to Word. This can e. g. done by installing and registering your AddIn in Word with an installer project.

Comment: The problem is that I can't build this Add-In (After pressing F5, an error message pops up.).

Comment: Can you provide the error message amd the corresponding code?

Comment: The error message is shown in the attached picture, while the code can be found in the body of the post.